# How to create data quality check using snowflake scripting by creating procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My requirement is to create procedure in snowflake using SQL (not programming language) to validate data checks like distinct count of any column from given table.

I need to provide 2 arguments like table name(fully qualified) and column name which I need to check the distinct count. Output should be the distinct count of column when I call that procedure with 2 inputs-table name and column name.

Below is the code I tried but couldn't able to execute the code. Any lead is appreciated.

```
create or replace procedure DQ_CHECK (table_name string, COL_NAME STRING)
 returns STRING
 language sql as
 $$
declare
 query_str string;
 rs string ;
begin  
 query_str := 'select COUNT(DISTINCT' || :COL_NAME ||') from '|| :table_name;
 rs := (execute immediate :query_str);
 return rs;
 end;
 $$
;
```

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure why you would want to do this, as typing out the call to the SP isn't going to be any quicker than typing SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT... - but if you do want to do it then have a look at the documentation for the IDENTIFER keyword when referencing objects by name in SQL script

Comment: I have many other data quality checks to do. i am trying with first one. Thanks for answer

Comment: `rs` is a result set. You can only return a resultset if the return type for the procedure is `table`. You will need to read the resultset (normally using a cursor), and return that value. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets#using-a-resultset